# Render component from variable Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

May i do something in Angular 9?

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-custom",
    template: "<h1>Hey, it's me!</h1>"
})
export class CustomComponent {

}

@Component({
    selector: "app-parent",
    template: "{{ someComponent }}"
})
export class Parent {

    someComponent: CustomComponent;

    constructor() {
        this.someComponent = new CustomComponent();
    }
}
```

I want to render component from variable.

This is example code, in my code i get "custom-component" from my contentchildren and want to render it with my changes

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding of what you're trying to do.

You have a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  public name: string = '';
}
```

You want to render that component using a variable.

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: "<ng-container #template></ng-container><p>Welcome</p>"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("template", { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
  private vcRef: ViewContainerRef;

  private componentType: Type<HelloComponent>;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentType = HelloComponent;

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      this.componentType
    );

    const componentRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<HelloComponent>componentRef.instance).name = "John";
  }
}
```

We use the [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator to find our "template" container, which will hold our component, and reference (read) it as a [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) object. This object will give us the ability to create and render our component.

The [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) will get the factory used to create our component.